# How can I modify webassembly filenames with webpack?

Tags: webpack, webassembly

In webpack.config.js, I know I can modify filenames of modules with this under module -> rules:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
  type: 'asset/resource',
  generator: {
    filename: 'static/[name][ext][query]'
  }
},
```

I want to do the same for a wasm file I am using. How can I do this?

I've tried a similar syntax as above, and that works but then the wasm file is not included correctly.

- is it possible to tell the webassembly module to change the filename?
- alternatively, is it possible to do this post-build or in some other way, while not breaking the build?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding to webpack.config.js:

```js
output: {
  ...
  webassemblyModuleFilename: 'mymodule.wasm'
}
```